# extjs form field width incorrect

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm having troubles with extjs' forms. In chrome, it looks fine until you focus on the first name field and the blur it, which then makes the input field too short. In IE, it's always too short. I have NO idea what's wrong. The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/lordzardeck/NmcXF/9/. You can't preview it for some reason in IE8 so you have to look here to see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/lordzardeck/NmcXF/9/show/light

Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added that to you fiddle and seems like it fixed it:

```
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },
```

Comment: awesome! that worked. i'll +1 if you explain why it didn't work before and why this one does

Comment: :) You need to play with different layouts and see how ExtJs arrange elements in them. I just like using 'anchor' layout for forms. That's pretty much it